# Scrolling issue with fixed divs in iframe on IOS

Tags: ios, html, css

I am having a problem with iOS scrolling on an iPad. Every other platform tested works just fine. I love iOS, but hate it too. I was able to get the entire iframe contents scrolling within the parent, but there are two DIVs that are fixed that shouldn’t scroll within the iframe.

Before I spend a lot of time trying to work this out, I am just looking to leverage everyone’s experience for whether it, in fact, CAN be done. If it IS possible, then I will proceed to trying to work out a simple model and report it back for others. If experience shows that it can NOT be done, then you will all have saved me a lot of headache, not to mention time.

Here’s a drawing of what works on all other platforms but NOT iOS:

[image]

Simple question: Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, in fact, YES.

Comment: Could you elaborate _how_ this is done as well? To improve the answer and to help fellow users?